# create sequence message text in windows application

Tags: c#

I want to create a sequence of message using textbox when my program is running. I was create a windows application to read a data from a data table and stored into database table. In that time am using a multiline text box to show continuous message. But i can't do this. The message show at the end of the process complete..

please help me to do this..

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your code on a background thread so that the UI is able to update.

Use the `BackgroundWorker` class and its progress reporting functionality.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: I don't need this kind of loader. I want to show the custom message sequentially..

Comment: @Amulraj: Wrong; you do need this.  The problem is that your code is running on the UI thread, which prevents the UI from updating.